# Using a string constant as a mysql query (with some steroids)

Tags: php, parameters, constants

Well there's a challenge for PHP gurus:

I'm developing an application that use a huge number of MySql queries distributed in a great bunch of files and functions. Those queries uses, obviously, some parameters derived from the functions that contains them.

My goal is: group all those queries on a single constants file, but maintain the functionality. There's an example:

This is an example function:

```
public function doQuery ($aParameter) {
    .
    .
    .
    $sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id = '".$aParameter."'");
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And this is what I want to do, using constants:

```
public function doQuery ($aParameter) {
    .
    .
    .
    $sqlQuery = mysql_query(THE_QUERY);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

As you can see, the problem is that if I use a defined constant as the query, it loses the parameter that I need to use to get the correct data from database.

So the final question is: There's a way to define a constant than can contain a variable to be determined when the constant is used? Something like:

```
define("THE_QUERY",     "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id = '".$aParameter."'");
```

Comment: I wouldn`t recommend this because you can end up having spaghetti code, in my opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with a parameterized query:

```
define("Q_QUERY1", "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id = :1"); 
$cn = new PDO();
/* more code ... */
$arr = array();
$arr[":1"] = $parameterValue;

$s = $cn->prepare(Q_QUERY1);
$s->execute($arr);
```

The main idea is to have constants or even files to store queries (for example so you can have a query for sqlserver and another for mysql...) with the parameters declared inside with some kind of custom recognizable notation (`:1`, `:PARAM1`, etc.) that you have to match within an associative array such as `$arr[":1"]` in this case.

The `->execute` method will match the parameters to the values for you, protecting your query against sql injections and adding the quotes around the parameters when necessary.

If you need specific data types you would need to use the `->bindParam` method instead to specify a `PDO::PARAM_XXX` parameter of your choice. 
The php documentation is pretty helpful if you need further details: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php

Comment: Nice! Lot of time without programming in PHP I suppose... I'll try :)

Comment: Absolutely awesome my friend. Works like a charm. Thank you very much.